Google Sheets: Index and Match - Find the dated column greater than today that has a value for a specific row
Given the set below:


A2 is =today(), resolving to the date value of Apr-19
range D2:2 (D2 and onwards to the right) are a list of dates
A4 is a product that im expecting to be shipped
range D4:4 (D4 and onwards to the right) are the number of units of A4 im expecting to arrive by their corresponding date on row D2:AH
The sample is simplified but row 4 downwards is dynamic and I can have more items on that table

I need:

Cell B4 to return the value from range D4:4 of the latest date that's more than A2 (today)

Samples:

A2 = Apr 19, then B4 = 130 (from Apr 23)
A2 = Apr 22, then B4 = 130 (from Apr 23)
A2 = Apr 23, then B4 = 0 (from Apr 24)

I tried using INDEX and MATCH but I can't get the "Greater than today" part for match.
Thanks in advance.

I managed to get what I needed by combining CHOOSEROWS, TOCOL, and FILTER from this answer and harun24hr's answer.
Here it is in action:
=CHOOSEROWS(TOCOL(FILTER(D4:4,D$2:$2>A$2),1),-1)


Try FILTER() and SORT() first. Then use INDEX() to grab the desired result.
=INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D2:4,D2:2>=A2)),1,0),1,3)



Hi, thanks for the help but this fails if the returned value is less than the last value on it's left. e.g. try changing value of I4 to 5 in your example

this gave me an idea. thank you so much! im upvoting your answer.
